# Unity3D Webplayer : How to know where i'm loaded

Tags: unity-game-engine

I wanna know in what website is the unity3D webplayer loaded **from the unity3D client**.

I don't want to do it using Javascript for security reasons.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [Application.absoluteURL](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Application-absoluteURL.html) ?

Comment: That's the unity player file , not the url where the client is loading.